# Install Ipython notebook without Internet connection

Tags: ipython

I followed these instructions:
http://ipython.org/install.html

Used last way to install (downloading source and "python setup.py install").

After that, console ipython worked fine, but trying to run notebook gave me error.

I always searched errors in Google and it always was a missing package.
Notebook probably depends on external packages.

After manually installing 2 packages it still gave me error.
Gave up and uninstalled everything (including Python itself).

Is there any way to manually download and install the notebook?
Do you know of any finite number of files/packages I have to download and install so the notebook will run just fine?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to give more info: What OS are you using? What version of python? ...

Comment: Python 2.7.9 32 bit, windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Windows, I suggest you to install [Winpython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/).

It includes all the libraries and tools (e.g. IPython) you will need in the same executable. So you only need to download the desired version and then you can pass that version using a USB stick to the computer without internet.

Comment: hello.thank you. i actually TRIED winpython before trying install ipython myself ontop of python official release. it did not work. now i realised why - had very bad luch and fall on buggy winpython release (2.7.6.3), in which ipython notebook does not work: http://sourceforge.net/p/winpython/tickets/107/ . just installed new version of winpython and everything works just fine.